# Node async/await don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I'm trying to use fewer callbacks in my code, so I think in a solution using async/await, but this is not working, express send the render the view before the query is complete.

The results of queries are fine, but after render.

**node -v = 8.9.1**

**controller code:**

```
app.get('/admin', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), (req, res, next) => {

  app.infra.connectionFactory(async (err, connection) => {  

    const blogDAO = new app.infra.BlogDAO(connection);

    const emailCount = await blogDAO.countLeads((errDAO, results) => {
    if (errDAO) {
        return next(errDAO);
    }
    return results[0].leads;
    });

    const userDAO = new app.infra.UserDAO(connection);
    const subCount = await userDAO.countUsers((errDAO, results) => {
    if (errDAO) {
        return next(errDAO);
    }
    return results[0].users;
    });

    const postCount = 3;

    res.render('admin/index', { emailCount, subCount, postCount });
  });
});
```

**DAO code:**

```
UserDAO.prototype.countUsers = function countUsers(callback) {
  this.connection.query('SELECT COUNT(token) AS users FROM users', callback);
};
```

Comment: Do you realize that `await` only works with functions that return a promise and when that promise is linked to when the async operation completes?  You're using `await blogDAO.countLeads(...)` on a function that takes a callback and does not return a promise.  It won't `await` anything.  In fact, `countUsers()` has NO return value at all so there's nothing for `await` to do.  You need to read a lot more about how `await` actually works and is used properly.

Comment: Question: *Does `await` make asynchronous code synchronous?*, Answer: ***Nothing** can make asynchronous code synchronous*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword **await** makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result. For more info check [here](http://javascript.info/async-await).

You need to change your code to

**DAO Code**

```
UserDAO.prototype.countUsers = function countUsers() {
  return this.connection.query('SELECT COUNT(token) AS users FROM users');
};
```

Make countUsers function return a promise.

**Controller Code**

```
try {
    const result = await userDAO.countUsers();
    const subCount = result[0].leads; // Or anything that will work with result
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err); // Handle the error
}
```

Wait till promise settles. If it resolve, the result will be in subCount and if reject or error occurs, it should be handled by catch block.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by using a promise library like bluebird and promisify things with callbacks.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Something like:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

app.get('/admin', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), (req, res, next) => {

  app.infra.connectionFactory(async (err, connection) => {

    const blogDAO = Promise.promisifyAll(new app.infra.BlogDAO(connection))
    const results = await blogDAO.countLeadsAsync();
    const emailCount = results[0].leads;
....
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to finish the queries at least for me has been using the async module, as you have mentioned you want the queries to be executed before the render method.

What does it do? Runs a bunch of functions with callbacks and saves the result in a variable. No need to delve into promises!

I have given an example below.

```
const all= require('../Model/all'); // This is the model which I'm calling
const async=require('async');  // You need to install this one

exports.edit = async function(req, res){
    id=req.params.id;
    table=req.params.table;
    department_companies=[];
    first_query=[];
    second_query=[];

    async.parallel({
            record: async.apply(all.getRecord,table,id),
            first_query: async.apply(all.viewPrimaryKeys,"first_table"),  // viewPrimaryKeys has 2 params: Table name and Callback
            second_query: async.apply(all.viewPrimaryKeys,"second_table"),
        }
        ,function(err,results){
            res.render('team/edit', {
                id: id, 
                record: results["record"],
                first_query: results["first_query"],
                second_query: results["second_query"]
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Run an `async.parallel` on all the functions using `async.apply` for each of those functions, with the `res.render` in the output function, hope that helps!